# MTLTexture from MTLBuffer issue

Tags: ios, fragment-shader, metal, metalkit, mtlbuffer

I have results of compute shader stored in MTLBuffer. Each element of MTLBuffer is a UInt16. I am trying to pass the results to a fragment shader that displays the result by interpreting the elements of MTLBuffer as color intensity between 0 to 255. I create an MTLTexture out of this MTLBuffer using following code and pass the texture to shader. But I think something is not correct in the process as the output is not correct. I am not sure if it is an issue with pixel format and/or format 
conversions.

```
    let textureDescriptor = MTLTextureDescriptor()
    textureDescriptor.textureType = .type2D
    textureDescriptor.pixelFormat = .r16Uint
    textureDescriptor.width = bufferWidth
    textureDescriptor.height = 256
    textureDescriptor.usage = [.shaderRead, .shaderWrite]


    let texture = buffer?.makeTexture(descriptor: textureDescriptor, offset: 0, bytesPerRow: bufferWidth*MemoryLayout<UInt16>.stride)
```

and here is fragment shader code,

```
   fragment half4 fragmentShaderDisplay (MappedVertex in [[ stage_in ]],
                                              texture2d<ushort, access::sample> lumaTexture  [[ texture(0) ]]
                                              )
{
    constexpr sampler s(t_address::clamp_to_edge, r_address::clamp_to_edge, min_filter::linear, mag_filter::linear);

    float luma = lumaTexture.sample(s, in.textureCoordinate).r/255.0;

    luma = clamp(0.0, luma, 1.0);

   return half4(luma, luma, luma, 1.h);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In what sense do you want to interpret the buffer values as between 0 and 255? Their inherent range is 0 to 65535 and the range for a floating-point component would typically be 0.0 to 1.0. Neither of those is 0 to 255.

If you simply divide by 65535.0 instead of 255.0, you'll get what you seem to want, a value between 0.0 and 1.0.

Also, your call to `clamp()` seems wrong. Given the order of arguments you've written, you're clamping the constant value 0.0 to be between `luma` and 1.0. I think you want to clamp `luma` to be between 0.0 and 1.0.

As it happens, the way you've written things will mostly work. If `luma` is <= 0.0, 0.0 will be between `luma` and 1.0 and will be returned unmodified. If 0.0 < `luma` <= 1.0, then 0.0 is below the range, so `clamp()` will return the lower bound of the range, which is `luma`. The problem comes if `luma` > 1.0. In that case, the results of `clamp()` are undefined, as per the documentation.

Now, values greater than 1.0 shouldn't happen if you're dividing by the proper divisor. Indeed, there's no need to clamp at all.

Comment: I want to interpret the numbers between 0 and 255, even if they are higher than 255, I wish to clamp them to 255.

Comment: clamp(x, minVal, maxVal ) = min(max(x, minVal), maxVal). In that case, does the order of x and minVal matter?

Comment: The documentation for `clamp()` specifically says that its result is undefined if `minVal` is greater than `maxVal` or, in the terms used in your code `luma` is greater than 1.0.